# Recession cone characterization.

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a convex, closed and not-bounded set. **Let $d$ be a vector which $||d||=1$**, then show that:

$d \in recc(\mathbb{C})$ $\iff$ $\exists$ $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{C}$ which $\lim\limits_{k \longrightarrow \infty}||x_k||=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{k \longrightarrow \infty}(x_k/||x_k||)=d$

I am using the first definition of recession cone found here [Recession cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recession_cone).

I've done this implication $"\Leftarrow"$, but I can't get the another one.

Comment: What does $(x_k/=||x_k||)$ mean? Typo?

Comment: @Maksim It was a mistakw, edited.

Answer (score 0):

If '$\Rightarrow$' would be true, since 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}(x_k/||x_k||)=d$$
 any $d$ would be the limit of elements with norm 1 ($||\frac{ x_k}{||x_k||}|| =1$),  hence this will hold for the limit as well : $||d||=1 $.

But this is a contradiction, since in general the cone will not consist just of elements with norm $1$.

So '$\Rightarrow$' is not true.

Maybe there is something else missing ?

Comment: You are right. I added a new hypotheis